# display:none not working on <noscript> tag in IE7 or IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, noscript

I have the following tag that functions properly in each of the "modern" browsers except IE 7 and IE8.

```
<style type="text/css">
    noscript.show {
        display:inline;
    }
    noscript.hide {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
<noscript class="hide">Javascript is currently disabled in your browser.</noscript>
```

Can IE handle this on the noscript tag? If so, how?

Comment: How are you expecting it to function, and how does the behaviour of IE7/8 differ from what you expect? As far as I can tell, the `<noscript>` tag will always be hidden regardless of whether JS is available.

Comment: While an odd behaviour, why would you want to hide this with css anyway? Isn't the point to deliver this to users who don't have scripts enabled?

Comment: I have the <noscript> container on every page in my site because I want to provide the visitor with a fore-warning message. So by default, when javascript is disabled, the warning appears and there is a close button in the upper-right hand corner of the block that allows the user to "toggle the message" to an off state or "hide".

Comment: You've piqued my curiousity. If JavaScript isn't available, how do you turn the message off?  That sounds like something which would require scripting.

Comment: I am using a session variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe IE just dont like the  tag, you could try the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
    p.show {
        display:inline;
    }
    p.hide {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
<noscript><p class="hide">Javascript is currently disabled in your browser.</p></noscript>
```

Comment: Thanks Mash. Moving the class style to the 'p' tag did the trick. I was hoping not to have to add additional markup, but I guess that's what IE does to you.

Comment: What a nasty hack. +1 anyways :-)

Comment: Yeah that's a bit nasty, but IE is even more nasty with CSS, hehe :P

Comment: BTW...I just tested the style on the p-tag in the "real" browsers and it works there also...not that I would have expected otherwise. Thanks again Mash.

Comment: If you don't want to add the 'p' tag, maybe you could add 'style="display:none;"' on the fly with javascript  
something like: getElementsByTagName('noscript').style.display='none'; Not 100% sure IE will accept this though

Comment: Nah...can't do it that way (according to my purpose). I do not want to rely on javascript in anyway -- hence the reason why I am trying to control the <noscript> container.

Comment: Haha, true. That's a good point :P 
Little are the chances javascript will work in a <noscript>.

Comment: so if you're able to control the HTML server-side, why don't you simply not serve the `<noscript>` tag in the event you don't want it shown; seems like it would be just as easy as changing the class.

Comment: Could be... and I guess I would need to think that through more (in my spare time). But my initial reaction is that I want the browser to use the power behind the <noscript> tag to determine if/if not javascript is disabled. So I ventured off to use the <noscript> tag for that purpose and I simply control the message through a toggle feature.

Comment: BTW...I needed to put that class attribute on both the additional <p> tag as well as the <noscript> tag. Without that class attr on the noscript tag, it wasn't working in Firefox.